# Thumbnail image in child list on Wordpress sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get thumbnail image in the child list on WordPress sidebar list. I didn't get to know how to integrate the code for the thumbnail image. Please help me.

here is my code below:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages()
{
  global $post;

  if(is_page() && $post->post_parent)
    $childpages=wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0');
  else
    $childpages=wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');

  if($childpages)
    $string='<ul class="list-unstyled">'.$childpages.'</ul>';

  return $string;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom query and in that query you can change argument based on the condition. Inside the loop, you can use `the_post_thumbnail()` to display featured image of the post.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {
    global $post;
    ob_start();

    $qargs = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    );

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        $qargs['post_parent'] = $post->post_parent;
    } else {
        $qargs['post_parent'] = $post->ID;
    }

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) : ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );
```

Comment: Thank you dear, Its working!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with functions. Write WP_Query to get the Thumbnail image in the child list. It will work as wp_list_pages.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {

global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
$child_pages_query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent ,
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order'
);
else
$child_pages_query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order'
);

$child_pages = new WP_Query( $child_pages_query_args );

if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) :
?>
<ul class="child_page_row">
<?php 
while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
            <div class="child_page_thumb">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 240)); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="child_page_name">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
</ul>
<?php    
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```